# Strange behavior when finding range of values between two numbers

Tags: c++

I've recently started working through the "c++ primer 5th Edition". I'm currently on the following exercise:

> Exercise 1.11: 
>   Write a program that prompts the user for two integers.
>   Print each number in the range specified by those two integers.

I have written the following code as a solution :

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int num1 = 0, num2 = 0;
    std::cout << std::endl << "Please enter two numbers to find a range between" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> num1 >> num2; 


    if (num1 < num2)
        while (num1 <= num2){
            std::cout << std::endl << num1;
            ++num1;
        }

    if (num2 < num1)
        while (num2 <= num1){
            std::cout << std::endl << num2;
            ++num2;
        }

    if (num1 == num2)
        std::cout << std::endl << num1;

    std::cout << std::endl;
```

However when I input the numbers, the output is not quite correct;

Sample input:

```
Please enter two numbers to find a range betweem
>> 1 5
```

Sample output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
5
6
```

What I don't understand, is that if the first number i input is larger than the first (e.g. num1 > num2), then the program produces the desired result, eg:

```
Please enter two numbers to find a range between
>> 5 1


1
2
3
4
5
```

What is particularly confusing is that, when I swap the order of the conditional statements, the first example will work correctly and the second will produce incorrect output.

Just to be clear, I'm aware of a cleaner, correct solution to this exercise. I would just like to know the reason that my program functions this way.

I'd very much appreciate an explanation!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its so simple.
Just add 'else' for the bottom two if loops
Basically you need to go through only 1 'if' loop, but your program goes through each 'if' loop

Comment: Just to add some more clarification, if your program goes to the first condition, it ends with `num1` always being greater than `num2`, thus triggering the second condition as well.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are increamenting your `num1` in the first condition when all iterations of `while` loop completed your second `if condition` gets true because its the loop exit condition of first `if`(i.e. num1 <= num2), so your second if triggered and print the last `5 6` .

While in second case your first `if` not triggered and you reach the second `if` and hence your flow works properly

Answer (score 1):

As Technoid said, add else statements. Your code should now become:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int num1 = 0, num2 = 0;
    std::cout << std::endl << "Please enter two numbers to find a range between" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> num1 >> num2; 


    if (num1 < num2)
        while (num1 <= num2){
            std::cout << std::endl << num1;
            ++num1;
        }

    else if (num2 < num1)
        while (num2 <= num1){
            std::cout << std::endl << num2;
            ++num2;
        }

    else if (num1 == num2)
        std::cout << std::endl << num1;

    /* Alternatively for (num1 ==num2) use:

    else
        std::cout << std::endl << num1;     

    */

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up changing it to, thanks for confirming